# DocumentDB Java SDK - Get Resource Units

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-java-sdk

I am trying to get the currently allocated RUs for a DocumentDB collection using Java SDK. Anyone have any inputs?

Comment: Please share any code that you’ve written so far regarding this and the issues you’re running into with that code.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a way to query for the Offer or OfferV2 of the collection.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-java/blob/529858e6c958795b8d704bce2535bf89af8fa286/sdk/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/cosmosdb/OfferV2.java) OfferV2 has a set and get method of the collection throughput. 
Offer (v1) will also contain the property as it's a Resource at it's code

You can read the offer using the `readOffer(string collectionSelfLink)` method in `AsyncDocumentClient` in order to retrieve the Offer and then use 
 `offer.getContent().getInt("offerThroughput");` to get the RU/s of the collection.

Casting it to `OfferV2` should work as well which gives you access to the `getOfferThroughput()` (which for the record internally will do what the line above does)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
  public int getRequstUnits(DocumentClient client, DocumentCollection coll) {
        return getOffer(client, coll).getContent().getInt("offerThroughput");
  }
```

Look at the **[`complete code sample`](https://github.com/guerard/pubmed-search/blob/0cc496fc171e1fa1452f4f8996c74340b96ed0ab/src/main/java/com/pubmed/search/cosmo/CosmoDbRequestUnitsManager.java)** here